# Продолжение работы скрипта после разрыва соединения со стороны пользователя WebSocket Django

Tags: django, websocket

В проекте имеется класс (AsyncWebsocketConsumer), тело которого может быть выполнено для определенного объекта в таблице базы данных - только раз в сутки. При разрыве соединения со стороны пользователя - обрывается выполнение вызванных функций, не давая возможность добавления результатов обработки в бд.

Возможно ли сделать продолжение выполнения кода, уже после разрыва соединения, или лучше добавить поля флагов выполнения работы, что бы при запуске скрипта повторно - выполнение продолжалось с того места, на котором закончилось?

Comment: Таск на celery для фоновых задачек

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу посоветовать этот гайд 
https://dizballanze.com/ru/django-project-optimization-part-3/.
Обрати внимание на библиотеку django-cacheops
В твоём Consumer придется прописать в функциях connect и disconnect методы для работы с кэшированием запросов к БД.